# Regarding the alignment of bits

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

Say I have two variables x and y, and I want to align the most significant 1s, how would I write this in C? For example, I have x=11 and y = 1011, and I want to align x with y by making it 1100. How could I do this?

Comment: You'd need to 1) determine the most significant bit in both numbers, then 2) shift the smaller integer that #/places to the left.

Comment: how can I determine the most significant bit of a variable integer?

Comment: Q: How can I determine the most significant bit of a variable integer?  A: Google "c most significant bit".  You'll find lots of algorithms ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a [BitScanReverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxyd7zd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)(or appropriate intrinsic for you compiler, like `__builtin_clz` for GCC), subtract the smaller from the larger and shift the smaller to the left by the difference.

Comment: I think you mean to the left.

Answer (score 0):

As paulsm4 suggested You can determine Most Significant "SET" bit of the number and Shift it.
Derived from that, a rather simplifed version could be:-

```
int Num1_bit_count = 0,Num2_bit_count = 0;
int Num1 = 0b1100, Num2 = 0b0011, temp = 0;

    temp = Num1;  //Let's copy it in other variable to save the value of Num1
     //Count Number of bits in Num1
     while(temp > 0)
     {
         temp = temp >> 1;
         Num1_bit_count++;

     }
    //Same for Num2
    temp = Num2;  //Let's copy it in other variable to save the value of Num2
     //Count Number of bits in Num1
     while(temp > 0)
     {
         temp = temp >> 1;
         Num2_bit_count++;

     }

  if(Num1_bit_count > Num2_bit_count)
   {
       Num2 = Num2 << (Num1_bit_count - Num2_bit_count);

   }
  else if(Num2_bit_count > Num1_bit_count)
   {
       Num1 = Num1 << (Num2_bit_count - Num1_bit_count);

   }
```